# Can't add legend into my graph on ggplot, Why is this the case?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add a legend it shows black for the 7 day moving average and blue for the bars(daily cases). so it looks something similar to the NHS graph , but the legend does not work when i add it into my code?

```
      ggplot(LimerickNew1, aes(x=TimeStamp, y=DailyCCase,Shape=MA7)) + 
      geom_bar(stat="identity",fill="steelblue") +
      geom_line(aes(y=MA7),size=1.5) +






   labs( x="", y="Total cases", title="Total Covid Cases for County Limerick 01-03-20 to 01- 
    06-`20" )+`
   theme_bw()+
   theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill = "darkgray"),
   legend.key = element_rect(fill = "lightblue", color = NA),
   legend.key.size = unit(1.5, "cm"),
   legend.key.width = unit(0.5,"cm"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", color="#008000",size=12, angle=0),
    axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", color="#008000",size=12, angle=0),
    axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", size=12, color="black"),
    plot.title  = element_text( face = "bold", colour = "black", size = 20,, hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please make your example minimal (e.g. omit themes and axis label formatting) and reproducible (we don't have `LimerickNew1` in our R sessions).

Comment: That said, I think `geom_col(aes(fill = "DailyCCase")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=MA7, colour = "7 day moving average"), size=1.5)` should get you one step further, but this is naturally untested.

Answer (score 0):

Without a reproducible example, it's hard to give a more specific answer for your question, but here's a method that expands upon the comment from @teunbrand and should guide you toward showing a legend.

TL;DR - The reason you're not seeing a legend is because you do not have any layers or geoms drawn that have one of the aesthetics mapped to `aes()`.  All aesthetics like color, size, and fill are specified for each geom outside of an `aes()` function, which means there's no reason for `ggplot2` to draw a legend.  To get a legend to be drawn, you need to specify the aesthetic inside `aes()`.

### Example

Here's an illustrative example that is similar to OP's question.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(8675309)
df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:100,
  y = rnorm(100, 10))

df$z <- log(cumsum(df$y))

ggplot(df, aes(x=x)) +
  geom_col(aes(y=y), fill='blue', alpha=0.3) +
  geom_line(aes(y=z), size=2) +
  ylim(0,25) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

### Showing a Legend

To get a legend to show, you have to specify one or more aesthetics inside `aes()`.  The fun fact here is that you don't have to specify a column in the dataset when doing this.  If you specify a single value, it will apply to the whole dataset, and basically just show a legend key for the entire set of observations.  This is what we want.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x)) +
  geom_col(aes(y=y, fill="the columns"), alpha=0.3) +
  geom_line(aes(y=z, size="the line"), color="black") +
  ylim(0,25) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

### Formatting

The names come from the values specified in `aes()`, and the color change is due to default mapping of color values.  To get things to look "right", you want to use some `theme()` elements to:

- keep only one name
- squish legends together
- position on the chart, rather than on the side

The end result is here:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x)) +
  geom_col(aes(y=y, fill="the columns"), alpha=0.3) +
  geom_line(aes(y=z, size="the line"), color="black") +
  ylim(0,25) +
  scale_fill_manual(values="blue") +  # recolor the columns
  guides(
    fill=guide_legend(title="My Legend", order=1),
    size=guide_legend(title=NULL, order=2)
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  
  # legend placement and spacing
  theme(
    legend.title = element_text(margin=margin(b=10)),
    legend.spacing.y = unit(-3,'pt'),
    legend.position = c(0.8, 0.8)
  )
```

[image]